# Jest/Enzyme Test Function Call in Callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

Problem: I am trying to achieve 100% test coverage using Jest with my React component, but it just doesn't seem to detect the function being called. I tried to extract out only the relevant parts below:

LinkedRepos.js:

```
import { auth } from "../../firebase";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { navigate } from "@reach/router";

const ReposPage = () => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (!user) {
        console.log("DEBUGGING NO USER");
        navigate("/");
      }
    });
  }, []);
};
export default ReposPage;
```

LinkedRepos.test.js

```
import React from "react";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";
import ReposPage from "../Components/Pages/LinkedRepos";
import { navigate } from "@reach/router";

jest.mock('@reach/router', () => ({
  navigate: jest.fn(),
}))

describe("Linked repos page", () => {
  it("not logged in", () => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    jest.spyOn(React, 'useEffect').mockImplementation(f => f());
    const repopage = shallow(<ReposPage />);
    expect(navigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  })
});
```

The test output:

```
  ● Linked repos page › not logged in

    expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(expected)

    Expected number of calls: 1
    Received number of calls: 0

....

    console.log src/Components/Pages/LinkedRepos.js:14
      DEBUGGING NO USER
```

I can't seem to find any answers that apply to my problem. I know my code is quite bad, but does anyone know the reason why it won't detect the "navigate" function being called? Clearly, it is reaching that point in the code, since it is printing out my debugging message. I just can't seem to wrap my head around testing.

Comment: Couple things: 1.) you're mocking `useEffect`, so `navigate` will never be called. 2.) `auth.onAuthStateChanged()` is adding an event handler to some object, but as far as i can see, nothing is triggering that event. I would un-mock useEffect, and then trigger/await the appropriate event on the `auth` object. A simpler test may be to check the expected effect: that you end up on the `/` route when no user is found

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm not sure what exactly mocking useEffect does, but if I move `navigate()` call outside of `auth.onAuthStateChanged()`, then Jest detects the function call normally. Could you clarify (2) and what I should do to trigger the event? I want to try and test it this way, but if there is no way then I will look into just checking the expected effect

Comment: I am not familiar w/firebase, you should refer to their documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I justed needed an await statement for Jest to recognise that navigate was being called. The final code is something like this:

```
it("should call navigate once if not logged in", async () => {
  await mount(<ReposPage />);
  expect(navigate).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```